# What is the format of the values in the img matrix given by load_untouch_nii in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, imaging, medical, nifti

I am working with MRI scans in NIFTI (.nii) format using MATLAB. My code is the following:

```
pha_nii=load_untouch_nii(filename_unzip_pha);
```

Where filename_unzip_pha is the name of a raw phase MRI scan in .nii format. According to documentation, pha_nii.img is the 3D matrix of nifti data. However, I have no idea what format these values are in/what their units are, and I need to convert it to the complex data type.

```
class (pha_nii.img)
```

tells me that it is of the int16 type, but I do not know the units of this data. One method I've seen does the following to convert to complex:

```
pha = double(pha_nii.img)/2048 - 1) * pi;
complex = exp(-1i*pha);
```

But I  have no idea what this is doing. If anyone has any insight, it would be much appreciated!

EDIT: load_untouch_nii is a MATLAB function for NIFTI processing--see documentation here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/8797/versions/28/previews/load_untouch_nii.m/index.html?access_key=

Comment: What is `load_untouch_nii`? This is not a function provided by MATLAB. Please see: [mcve].

Comment: I have changed my post slightly, please see it for documentation link